# Incorrect Regex in XML node string

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I'm trying to get a `Regex` to work, but several hours later still can't crack it!

Let's say I have this lines (in XML):

```
<MyXMLTag DataMember="$$Date$$" Name="$$DateName$$" DateTimeGroupInterval="MonthYear" DefaultId="$$MyId$$" />

<NameTag>$$item$$</NameTag>
```

I need to get the words that start and end with `$$`, but only the ones that don't start with "`DataMember="`".

Ideal is only the ones that aren't inside `DataMember="..."`.

So, in this case I wanted the matches `$$Date$$`, `$$MyId$$` and `$$item$$`. The `$$DateName$$` should be ignored/discarted.

So far I've tried the following Regex combinations:

```
@"(?<!^\bDataMember="\b)\$\$(.*?)\$\$"

@"(?<!(\w*DataMember="\w*))\$\$(.*?)\$\$"
```

I had several other variations of the same, but none of them allowed me to achieve my goal.

With these combinations I had this (incorrect) result:

```
$$" Name="$$
$$" Name="$$
$$" DateTimeGroupInterval="MonthYear" DefaultId="$$
```

Has you can see it's catching the words between XML attributes!

What I want is to replace the text between `$$` with a custom one.

I don't need to handle the XML itself, for that I can use multiple tools, but only the text betwen `$$`. Consider that the code doesn't know if the text is inside a tag, an attribute, the root node, a child node, one or multiple times...

Help?!

Comment: Why are you trying to parse XML using regex, instead of using a dedicated XML parser?  Regex is not a good tool for this.

Comment: Sure you could try `(?<=(?<!\bDataMember=)")\$\$[^"]*?\$\$(?=")`, but you really should think of using the right tool for the task.

Comment: No @Amy, you can ignore the XML part (just an example). It can be as simple as a `string` line with a similar format (eg: `Key="$$key$$"`).

Comment: We cannot ignore that. Once you post an example input, everyone will start thinking in the direction of whether the tool you are using is appropriate for the task. Parsing XML with regex in C# is truly meaningless when you have all the tools ready.

Comment: If your input is well-formed XML, I would *always* go with the XML parser and just not bother with regex at all.  If it *isn't* well-formed, I would use a more forgiving HTML parser, and still not use regex.

Comment: There are cases when the XML is formed using non-XML tools, and with several assumptions you could use a regex, but still, when you need to get some value from some markup text except in a specific element, you first need to get the element, regex is unaware of the *structure*.

Comment: In this case is an XML, but I don't want to handle the XML itself, but replace the text inside the `$$` prefix+sufix with a custom text, but only in certain cases. The main reason is I don't know the XML format when this happens. The text can be in a tag, an attribute, can be in the root node, a child node, etc

Comment: Just edited the question with more information. Don't know if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of matching *anything* between the two `$$` delimiters, look for consecutive word characters instead:

```
new Regex(@"(?<!\bDataMember="")\$\$(\w+)\$\$");
```

Matches `$$DateName$$`, `$$MyId$$` and `$$item$$` alike